# How can I free uint32_t pointer?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, compilation

I'm newbie with pointer in c. I'm just testing code like this

```
void test(uint32_t *data)
{
    unsigned char raw_data[] = "this is a test data";
    unsigned char *raw = (unsigned char*)malloc(strlen((char*)raw_data));
    memcpy(raw, raw_data, strlen((char*)raw_data)+1);
    *data = (uint32_t)raw;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    uint32_t data;

    test(&data);
    printf("%s\n", data);
    if (data != NULL)
    {
        free(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use a `uint32_t` to store a `unsigned char*`, when I try to free `data`, I meet a error `error C2664: “void free(void *)”:   uint32_t can not convert to “void *"`.

How can I free `data`?

First, thanks to Phạm Anh Tuấn, Gerhardh, KBlr and son on. You are very kind.

**Solution:**

```
void test(uintptr_t *data)
{
    unsigned char raw_data[] = "this is a test data";
    unsigned char *raw = (unsigned char*)malloc(strlen((char*)raw_data) + 1);
    memcpy(raw, raw_data, strlen((char*)raw_data));
    raw[strlen((char *)raw_data)] = '\0';
    *data = (uintptr_t)raw;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    uintptr_t data;

    test(&data);
    printf("%s\n", data);
    if (data != NULL)
    {
        free((void *)data);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Must add a `'\0'` to `raw` as terminating string, then `free` works. And for working on `64bit`, change `uint32_t` to `intptr_t`.

Comment: `free((void *)data);` ? by the way your program will not work on `64bit` machine. For more info checkout size of pointer on 64bit machine.

Comment: Besides your pointer type problem, you have undefined behaviour as you do not allocate memory for terminatiing `\0` byte of the string.

Comment: Why are you writing such obscure code for though? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: `void test(uintptr_t *data) { return (uintptr_t)strdup("this is a test data"); }` is much shorter and way more clear

Answer (score -1):

Your program will not work on `64bit` machine since size of pointer on `64bit` machine is `8bytes`.

You can use `uintptr_t` instead `uint32_t` to hold the address.
While freeing cast the `uintptr_t` to `void*` as below sample code shows.

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void test(uintptr_t *data)
{
    unsigned char raw_data[] = "this is a test data";
    unsigned char *raw = (unsigned char*)malloc(strlen((char*)raw_data));
    memcpy(raw, raw_data, strlen((char*)raw_data)+1);
    *data = (uintptr_t)raw;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uintptr_t data;

    test(&data);
    printf("%s\n", (char *)data);
    if ((void *)data != NULL)
    {
        free((void *)data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only integer types guaranteed to support round-trip conversions from pointer to integer to pointer without loss of fidelity are `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`.  In particular, `size_t` is not guaranteed to have this property.